# Deedy Resume; How to bold text?

Tags: graphics, cv, deedy-resume

I've recently found the Deedy-Resume template (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/deedy-resume-cv) . However I would like to bold text in the body of the document, i.e., " \textbf{} doesn't work within the "tightemize" section. honestly I don't know how it can be done in this CV environment. Any suggestion?

I have attached the .cls and .tex extensions of the code below.Have a look

```
    % Intro Options
\ProvidesClass{deedy-resume-openfont}[2014/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

% Package Imports
\usepackage[hmargin=0.75cm, vmargin=0.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 

% Color definitions
\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666} 
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} 
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{6A6A6A}
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333}

% Set main fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text, Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}
\newcommand{\custombold}[1]{\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}\selectfont #1 \normalfont}

% Date command
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{3mm} % start everyth
\newcommand{\lastupdated}{\begin{textblock}{60}(165,0)
\color{date}\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont 
Last Updated on
\today
\end{textblock}}

% Name command
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
    \centering{
        \sffamily
        \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\fontsize{34pt}{8cm}\selectfont #1 
        \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2
    } \\
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \centering{ \color{headings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{10pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
    \vspace{-10pt}
}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

% Headings command
\titleformat{\section}{\color{headings}
\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\fontsize{16pt}{20pt}\selectfont \raggedright\uppercase}{} {0em}{}

% Subeadings command
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{subheadings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\newcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{\color{subheadings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase {#1} \normalfont}

% Descriptors command
\newcommand{\descript}[1]{\color{subheadings}\raggedright\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont}

% Location command
\newcommand{\location}[1]{\color{headings}\raggedright\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont {#1\\} \normalfont}

% Section seperators command
\newcommand{\sectionsep}[0]{\vspace{8pt}}

% Bullet Lists with fewer gaps command
\newenvironment{tightemize}{\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize}\itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}
```

and the .tex extension

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Deedy - One Page Two Column Resume
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (30/4/2014)
%
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX
%
% This template uses several fonts not included with Windows/Linux by
% default. If you get compilation errors saying a font is missing, find the line
% on which the font is used and either change it to a font included with your
% operating system or comment the line out to use the default font.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% TODO:
% 1. Integrate biber/bibtex for article citation under publications.
% 2. Figure out a smoother way for the document to flow onto the next page.
% 3. Add styling information for a "Projects/Hacks" section.
% 4. Add location/address information
% 5. Merge OpenFont and MacFonts as a single sty with options.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% CHANGELOG:
% v1.1:
% 1. Fixed several compilation bugs with \renewcommand
% 2. Got Open-source fonts (Windows/Linux support)
% 3. Added Last Updated
% 4. Move Title styling into .sty
% 5. Commented .sty file.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Known Issues:
% 1. Overflows onto second page if any column's contents are more than the
% vertical limit
% 2. Hacky space on the first bullet point on the second column.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     LAST UPDATED DATE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     TITLE NAME
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\namesection{Abhishek}{Arijit}{ \urlstyle{same}\url{} \\ 

}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN ONE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EDUCATION
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Education} 

\subsection{IIT Kharagpur}
\descript{Dual Degree (Hons.) | B.Tech in Mechanical Engineering | M.Tech in Manufacturing Science}
\location{July 2011 - 2016 | Kharagpur, India \\ Cum. GPA: 7.46/10}
\sectionsep


\subsection{BJB Junior College}
\location{Grad. June 2010|  Bhubaneshwar,  \\India, Cum. Grade: 76.67/100}
\sectionsep


\subsection{Monfort High School}
\location{Grad. June 2008|  Dhenkanal, India \\ Cum. Grade: 94.32/100}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     COURSEWORK
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Achievements}
\textbullet{} \textbf{Hardware Modelling} IITKGP Bronze('15), Gold('14), Bronze ('13), Gold ('12) \\ \textbullet{} \textbf{Product Design} IITKGP Silver('15), Silver ('14), Bronze ('13) \\\textbullet{} \textbf{Case Study} IITKGP Silver('15), Silver('14)\\ \textbullet{} Captain of 1 out of 3 teams selected for Tier-I funding by Innovation Cell IITKGP 
\sectionsep

\section{Coursework}
\subsection{Graduate}
Robotics \\
Computer Integrated Manufacturing \\
Knowledge Based Systems \\
Mechanics of Human Body \\
Mechanical Drives \\
\sectionsep

\subsection{Undergraduate}
Kinematics of Machines \\
Dynamics of Machines \\
Design of Machine Elements \\
Systems and Control \\
Machine Tools and Machining \\
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     SKILLS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Skills}
\subsection{Mechanical}
Humanoid Robotics \textbullet{} Rehabilitation Robotics \textbullet{} All-terrain Rovers \textbullet{} Powered Exoskeletons  \textbullet{} Manipulator Arm Design \\ \textbullet{} Dassault Solidworks \\
\sectionsep
\subsection{Computational}
Neural Networks \textbullet{} Fuzzy Logic Systems \\ \textbullet{} Genetic Algorithms \textbullet{} Soft Computing\\ \textbullet{} Regression Analysis \textbullet{} Pareto Optimality \\
\sectionsep

\subsection{Programming}
Matlab \textbullet{} C
\sectionsep



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
%     COLUMN TWO
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.67\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EXPERIENCE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Internships and Training}
\runsubsection{Mercedes-Benz India Private Limited}
\descript{| Intern }
\location{May 2014 – Jun 2014 | Pune, India}
\vspace{\topsep} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
\begin{tightemize}
\item Designed fixtures to optimize the assembly line to eliminate A/C leakage cases for the models E-Class and GL-Class, and identified the faulty assembly station and process \item Optimized grinding process at body shop to reduce rework time for E-Class model \item Analyzed and altered the door assembly process; critical to GL-Class' noise reduction\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Max Life Insurance Company Limited }
\descript{| Intern }
\location{Dec 2013| Hyderabad, India}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Researched and critically analyzed the Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence tools employed at Max Life Insurance vs the tools employed by its rivals in the market\item Proposed near optimal alterations based on size of Big data and market share  \end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{National Thermal Power Corporation}
\descript{| Summer Trainee}
\location{May 2013 – Jun 2013 | Kaniha, India}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Undertook training on working parameters of a 3000 MW thermal power plant with phases inclusive of procurement of raw material to generation of electricity\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     RESEARCH
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Research and Projects}
\runsubsection{Soft Computing Laboratory, Department of Mechanical Engineering, IIT Kharagpur}
\location{July 2014 – Present}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Algorithm for terrain adaptive gait cycle trajectory planning of a biped robot using multi-objective optimization with multi-layered feed forward neural networks 
\item Mechanical design and control aspects of a pseudo-anthropomorphic full body powered exoskeleton \item Intelligent Control of Lower Torso Joint Actuators of a pseudo-anthropomorphic powered exoskeleton to assist paraplegic patients’ locomotion using Neuro Fuzzy ANFIS Approach
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Hardware Modelling and Product Design Projects,    
    IIT Kharagpur}
\location{May 2012 - June 2015}
As Mechanical Team Head, was responsible for design of the prototypes from ground zero.
\begin{tightemize}
\item Bomb Retrieval and Universal Terrain Explorer - Prototype six wheeled all terrain rover with rocker-bogie differential bar traction maximization mechanism \item Walk Assistive Limb Kinetics Exoskeleton - Prototype Lower Torso Exoskeleton; uses pantograph mechanism; transforms from wheelchair to walking stance \item Arachne - Prototype suit that facilitates its user to scale walls using vacuum; capable of max-payload of 70kg exclusive of suit weight \item Power Augmentation Load Transmission Exoskeleton Prime - Prototype full body exoskeleton with pay-load capacity of 100 kgs \item Pristine - Portable RO - UV Water Purifier; optimal cost effective and modular design  \item Sparsh - easy-to-use, portable and affordable infant warmer for neonatal babies
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep
\runsubsection{Case Studies}
\location{February - March 2015}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Drishtee: Analyzed the Bottom of the Pyramid market potential and share in India \item Designed Fuzzy Classifier with support index, dependency and entrepreneurial coefficients as variables; and the problem specific Lloyd Max's Algorithm for heat map  
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     AWARDS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Position of Responsiblity}
\runsubsection{Captain} 
\location{July 2014 - April 2015} 
\begin{tightemize}
\item Led a team of 20 students at the Hardware Modelling Competition IIT KGP 2014-15 \item Planned and oversaw the execution of the all-terrain rover from scratch to prototype 
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     SOCIETIES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{minipage} 
\end{document}  \documentclass[]{article}
```

Comment: Can you copy paste the code you used and create a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: I used a template in the online latex editor ShareLatex. The link to the code is https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/deedy-resume

Comment: When I follow your link I've a page showing the output but nothing about code. You should just put this on on your post by editing it `;-)`

Comment: Done :) , included the code in the question

Comment: you can try `{\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\selectfont\bfseries some bold text}`

Comment: I don't understand where to add that piece of code

Comment: @AbhishekArijit Where you want the bold text to appear of course.

Comment: You linked to two different templates. Please be consistent, templates are a constant nightmare for helpers.

Comment: @touhami Please make that an answer. The code provided is from sharelatex, not latex-templates.

Comment: @Johannes_B done.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the code the solution is

```
{\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\selectfont\bfseries some bold text}
```

Comment: Finally the upvote you deserve for answering a template question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add it as a command to make your template neater.

```
%inline bold command for items
\newcommand{\inlinebold}[1]{\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\selectfont\bfseries {#1}
    \normalfont}
```

Use it like any other command

```
\begin{tightemize}
\item Designed fixtures to \inlinebold{optimize the assembly line} to eliminate A/C leakage cases for the models E-Class and GL-Class, and \inlinebold{identified the faulty assembly station and process}
\item Optimized grinding process at body shop to reduce rework time for E-Class model
\item Analyzed and altered the door assembly process; \inlinebold{critical to GL-Class'} noise reduction
\end{tightemize}
```