# Accents not rendered correctly \scshape

Tags: xetex, accents

As mentioned in this unanswered github issue: 
[Wrong accents with scshape](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume/issues/30),
there is an issue with the rendering of accented letters (Aeéeèuùaà) for the case of the command `\descript` defined in the same github repository.

Those letters should be displayed as small uppercase, but they are small case.

The template uses XeLaTeX and `Raleway` font. (You can get it from the git itself)

Relevant code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{deedy-resume-openfont}

\begin{document}

\descript{Accents should be displayed properly: J'ai la tête égarée. Aeéeèuùaà}

\end{document}

% Intro Options
\ProvidesClass{deedy-resume-openfont}[2014/04/30 CV class]

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/,BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,BoldFont=Lato-Reg,ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta]{Lato-Lig}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text, Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}

\newcommand{\descript}[1]{
\color{subheadings}\raggedright\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont}
```

I tried to add French support, without luck:

```
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please, add a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could see at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269436/deedy-resume-how-to-bold-text.

Comment: @Sebastiano My question is indeed about the same template, but in this case it is not about making text bold. I would like to know how to change the `\descript` command which includes `\scshape` not to break accents. Thanks

Comment: The Raleway font misses accented small caps. Change font. By the way, the code you show from the `deedy-resume-openfont` class is not what I'd call clean.

Comment: Oh, I see... For the code I just copy-pasted hastily the minimal part of the template that reproduced the error. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I wouldn't use this template. It hasn't been adapted for two years, its code contains tons of spurious spaces, and quite a lot of code is at least rather curious.

Comment: Well, any advice for a CV Template?

Comment: and for any document class, if using xetex do not use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (The first will force incorrect hyphenation and the second does nothing other than make a warning that it should not be used)

Comment: I have the same problem with this cv template from Deedy. did you finally get to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I made a few experiments with the Raleway font.

## First attempt

### Input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Raleway}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Medium,
  ItalicFont=*-Medium-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-Bold-Italic,
]

\begin{document}

This is text in Raleway

\textsc{Aeéeèuùaà}

\textsc{Ae\'ee\`eu\`ua\`a}

\end{document}
```

### Output (with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)

[image]

### Comments

The Raleway font has no small caps glyphs for the accented characters

## Second attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Raleway}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Medium,
  ItalicFont=*-Medium-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-Bold-Italic,
]

\def\UndeclareTextComposite#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\let\csname\expandafter\string\csname #1\string#2\endcsname-\string#3\endcsname\relax
}
\UndeclareTextComposite{TU}{\'}{e}

\begin{document}

This is text in Raleway

\textsc{Aeéeèuùaà}

\textsc{Ae\'ee\`eu\`ua\`a}

\end{document}
```

### Output with XeLaTeX

The same as before

### Output with LuaLaTeX

[image]

### Comments

The mysterious code I added removes the predefined combination `\'e`, so that the default combining acute character should be used.

The HarfBuzz library used by XeLaTeX seizes the initiative and chooses the predefined combination anyway, so the result is not different. With LuaLaTeX this does not happen but the combining acute accent U+0301 doesn't exist in the font, so we get the message

```
Missing character: There is no ́ (U+0301) in font [Raleway-Medium.otf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+smcp;!
```

and the “small caps e” does not receive an accent.

### Conclusion

The Raleway font is defective.

Besides, the code you show from the class is not really clean.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @egreg. I think I reached the limit of the template and I don't intend to focus deeper into it.
I am not definitely not fluent in Latex but I like the system so I intend to keep on using it for obtaining professional documents.
For this time it seems there is no proper solution.

Comment: @RémiDebette When a font doesn't have the needed glyphs, there's not much to do except changing it.

Comment: For what it is worth i reported it to the [Raleway git](https://github.com/impallari/Raleway/issues/21)